# OleDbException | file.mdb' is not a valid path

Tags: asp.net, oledb, plesk

I changed the location of my websites to my E drive.
We are using **Plesk** with **Asp.net** comp.

I've changed the location in `IIS -> Basic settings` to the correct location.
My connection string is:

```
LocalSQLSerer = data source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|aspnetdb.mdf;User Instance=true
```

I am getting this error from asp.net

```
[OleDbException (0x80004005): 'C:\Inetpub\vhosts\domain.com\httpdocs\dir\App_Data\WebExpl.mdb' is not a valid path.  Make sure that the path name is spelled correctly and that you are connected to the server on which the file resides.]
   System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnectionInternal..ctor(OleDbConnectionString constr, OleDbConnection connection) +971317
   System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions options, Object poolGroupProviderInfo, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningObject) +86
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreateNonPooledConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, DbConnectionPoolGroup poolGroup) +29
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.GetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection) +4911356
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.OpenConnection(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory) +117
   System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection.Open() +40
   Aster.Data.Access.DataSetAccess.OpenConnection(IDbConnection conn) +72
   Aster.Data.Access.DataSetAccess.FillData(DataTable dt, String order) +266
   Aster.Data.Access.DataSetAccess.FillData(DataSet ds, DataTable dt, String order) +63
   Aster.Data.Rules.DataSetRules.FillDataDirect(DbSettings dbSettings, DataSet ds, DataTable dt, String order) +86
   AppCache.InitCache() +166
   AppCache.get_MultiLanguages() +8
   BasePage.InitializeCulture() +190
   ASP.default_aspx.__BuildControlTree(default_aspx __ctrl) +93
   ASP.default_aspx.FrameworkInitialize() +22
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +56
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest() +80
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestWithNoAssert(HttpContext context) +21
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context) +49
   ASP.default_aspx.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context) +4
   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +181
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +75
```

Web.config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <sectionGroup name="system.web.extensions" type="System.Web.Configuration.SystemWebExtensionsSectionGroup, System.Web.Extensions, Version=1.0.61025.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35">
      <sectionGroup name="scripting" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingSectionGroup, System.Web.Extensions, Version=1.0.61025.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35">
        <section name="scriptResourceHandler" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingScriptResourceHandlerSection, System.Web.Extensions, Version=1.0.61025.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" requirePermission="false" allowDefinition="MachineToApplication" />
        <sectionGroup name="webServices" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingWebServicesSectionGroup, System.Web.Extensions, Version=1.0.61025.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35">
          <section name="jsonSerialization" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingJsonSerializationSection, System.Web.Extensions, Version=1.0.61025.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" requirePermission="false" allowDefinition="Everywhere" />
          <section name="profileService" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingProfileServiceSection, System.Web.Extensions, Version=1.0.61025.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" requirePermission="false" allowDefinition="MachineToApplication" />
          <section name="authenticationService" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingAuthenticationServiceSection, System.Web.Extensions, Version=1.0.61025.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" requirePermission="false" allowDefinition="MachineToApplication" />
        </sectionGroup>
      </sectionGroup>
    </sectionGroup>
    <section name="RewriterConfig" type="URLRewriter.Config.RewriterConfigSerializerSectionHandler, URLRewriter" />
  </configSections>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="errordetails" value="0" />
  </appSettings>
  <RewriterConfig>
    <!--  Url Rewrite rules: http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/default.asp?url=/library/en-us/dnaspp/html/urlrewriting.asp -->
    <Rules>
      <RewriterRule>
        <LookFor>(.*taxon)-(.*)\.aspx\??(.*)</LookFor>
        <SendTo>$1.aspx?t=$2$3</SendTo>
      </RewriterRule>
      <RewriterRule>
        <LookFor>(.*taxalist)-(.*)\.aspx\??(.*)</LookFor>
        <SendTo>$1.aspx?l=$2$3</SendTo>
      </RewriterRule>
    </Rules>
  </RewriterConfig>
  <system.codedom>
    <compilers>
      <compiler language="c#;cs;csharp" extension=".cs" compilerOptions="/d:TRACE" warningLevel="1" type="Microsoft.CSharp.CSharpCodeProvider, System, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089">
        <providerOption name="CompilerVersion" value="v3.5" />
        <providerOption name="WarnAsError" value="false" />
      </compiler>
    </compilers>
  </system.codedom>
  <system.web>
    <machineKey validationKey="4E7389973C005359F87CF6F715FB0360C330E2FC37EA40E313121537A78FCCC9FEF91DA2147DDD5D5D944D6A7A144D88616FF6775A1346A3B3D9832958332851" decryptionKey="A69F535808919FAE767057615E73283AC9B3CABE975C7E8BF3EF11CAB445F283" validation="SHA1" decryption="AES" />
    <browserCaps userAgentCacheKeyLength="256" />
    <pages theme="default" enableEventValidation="true" validateRequest="true" enableViewStateMac="true">
      <controls>
        <add tagPrefix="asp" namespace="System.Web.UI" assembly="System.Web.Extensions, Version=1.0.61025.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
      </controls>
    </pages>
    <!-- 50MB in Kbytes. Should be equal maxAllowedContentLength -->
    <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="51200" enableVersionHeader="false" />
    <customErrors mode="Off" defaultRedirect="errmsg.aspx" />
    <httpHandlers>
      <!-- IIS 6 -->
      <remove verb="*" path="*.asmx" />
      <add verb="*" path="*.asmx" validate="false" type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory, System.Web.Extensions, Version=1.0.61025.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
      <add verb="*" path="*_AppService.axd" validate="false" type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory, System.Web.Extensions, Version=1.0.61025.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
      <add verb="GET,HEAD" path="ScriptResource.axd" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptResourceHandler, System.Web.Extensions, Version=1.0.61025.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" validate="false" />
      <add verb="*" path="MapHandler.ashx" type="MapHandler,App_Code" />
      <add verb="*" path="*js.axd" type="ScriptCompressorHandler" />
    </httpHandlers>
    <httpModules>
      <!-- IIS 6 -->
      <remove name="WindowsAuthentication" />
      <remove name="PassportAuthentication" />
      <remove name="AnonymousIdentification" />
      <remove name="UrlAuthorization" />
      <remove name="FileAuthorization" />
      <add type="URLRewriter.ModuleRewriter, URLRewriter" name="ModuleRewriter" />
    </httpModules>
    <httpCookies httpOnlyCookies="true" requireSSL="true" />
    <sessionState mode="InProc" cookieless="false" timeout="10" />
    <!--<sessionState mode="StateServer" stateConnectionString="tcpip=localhost:42424" cookieless="false" timeout="10" />-->
  </system.web>
  <system.net>
    <connectionManagement>
      <add address="*" maxconnection="40" />
    </connectionManagement>
  </system.net>
  <system.web.extensions>
    <scripting>
      <webServices>
        <jsonSerialization maxJsonLength="2097152" />
      </webServices>
      <scriptResourceHandler enableCompression="true" enableCaching="true" />
    </scripting>
  </system.web.extensions>
  <!-- IIS 7 -->
  <system.webServer>
    <urlCompression doDynamicCompression="true" doStaticCompression="true" dynamicCompressionBeforeCache="true" />
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
      <remove name="WindowsAuthentication" />
      <remove name="PassportAuthentication" />
      <remove name="AnonymousIdentification" />
      <remove name="UrlAuthorization" />
      <remove name="FileAuthorization" />
      <remove name="UrlAddwww" />
      <remove name="ModuleRewriter" />
      <add name="ScriptModule" preCondition="integratedMode" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptModule, System.Web.Extensions, Version=1.0.61025.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
      <add type="URLRewriter.ModuleRewriter, URLRewriter" name="ModuleRewriter" />
    </modules>
    <handlers accessPolicy="Read, Write, Script, Execute">
      <remove name="WebServiceHandlerFactory-Integrated" />
      <add name="ScriptHandlerFactory" verb="*" path="*.asmx" preCondition="integratedMode" type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory, System.Web.Extensions, Version=1.0.61025.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
      <add name="ScriptHandlerFactoryAppServices" verb="*" path="*_AppService.axd" preCondition="integratedMode" type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory, System.Web.Extensions, Version=1.0.61025.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
      <add name="ScriptResource" preCondition="integratedMode" verb="GET,HEAD" path="ScriptResource.axd" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptResourceHandler, System.Web.Extensions, Version=1.0.61025.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
      <add name="MapHandler" verb="*" path="MapHandler.ashx" type="MapHandler,App_Code" />
      <add name="StrawberryPerl" path="*.pl" verb="GET,HEAD,POST" modules="CgiModule" scriptProcessor="C:\Strawberry\perl\bin\perl.exe &quot;%s&quot; %s" resourceType="Either" />
    </handlers>
    <staticContent>
      <clientCache cacheControlCustom="public" cacheControlMode="UseMaxAge" cacheControlMaxAge="30.00:00:00" />
    </staticContent>
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="HTTP/S to HTTPS Redirect" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url="(.*)" />
          <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
            <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="off" ignoreCase="true" />
            <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" negate="true" pattern="\.asmx$" ignoreCase="true" />
          </conditions>
          <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}/{R:1}" appendQueryString="true" redirectType="Permanent" />
        </rule>
        <rule name="Rewrite https imagelib request to http" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url="(.*)" />
          <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
            <add input="{URL}" pattern="^/unimusbilder/(.*)$" ignoreCase="true" />
          </conditions>
          <action type="Rewrite" url="http://www.unimus.no/felles/bilder/{C:1}" appendQueryString="true" />
        </rule>
      </rules>
      <outboundRules>
        <rule name="Add Strict-Transport-Security when HTTPS" enabled="true">
          <match serverVariable="RESPONSE_Strict_Transport_Security" pattern=".*" />
          <conditions>
            <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="on" ignoreCase="true" />
          </conditions>
          <action type="Rewrite" value="max-age=31536000" />
        </rule>
      </outboundRules>
    </rewrite>
    <httpProtocol>
      <customHeaders>
        <remove name="X-Powered-By" />
        <remove name="X-Powered-By-Plesk" />
        <add name="X-UA-Compatible" value="IE=Edge" />
        <add name="X-XSS-Protection" value="1;mode=block" />
        <add name="X-Frame-Options" value="SAMEORIGIN" />
        <add name="X-Content-Type-Options" value="nosniff" />
        <add name="Content-Security-Policy" value="default-src 'none'; connect-src 'self'; img-src *; script-src 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' *; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; font-src *; base-uri 'self'; form-action 'self'; frame-ancestors 'self'; " />
      </customHeaders>
    </httpProtocol>
    <security>
      <requestFiltering>
        <!-- 50MB in bytes, default is 30000000 (28.6102 Mb). Should be equal maxRequestLength -->
        <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="52428800" />
      </requestFiltering>
    </security>
  </system.webServer>
  <connectionStrings>
    <remove name="LocalMySqlServer" />
  </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

Any one know what the issue can be here?
I work mostly with WP pages and linux, this is greek for me.
These are goverment sites so feedback are higly appriciated

Comment: You posted a SQL Server connection string and an OLEDB exception clearly thrown by an attempt to read an Access database file. Debug your code and post the code that actually throws the error. What is `AppCache` and `BasePage`? `AppCache.InitCache` is clearly trying to load `Webexpl.mdb`

Comment: It was working great before we moved servers. So "nothing" wrong with the scripts.
Changing the location of the files messed this up

Comment: Did you read the exception text or the stack trace? This has nothing to do with SQL Server. The error complains about `'C:\Inetpub\vhosts\domain.com\httpdocs\dir\App_Data\WebExpl.mdb'`. Besides, what you posted is a SQL Server connection string, it *can't work with OLEDB*